# three.js rotate facing object

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, angle

I did vector stuff for already 13 years now, but am still struggling with the way three.js handles things. So what I like to do is best described with a fan that always faces the camera and, of course, rotates.

This is how I achieved this in another language:

```
// Create a vector facing in camera direction.
temp.x = 0;
temp.y = 1;
temp.z = 0;
vec_rotate(temp, camera.pan);

// Apply vector direction to scene object.
vec_to_angle(entity.pan, temp);

// Rotate scene object's angle around another angle / imaginary line from camera to object.
ang_rotate(
    entity.pan, 
    vector(random(360), 0, 0)
);
```

Thus, after applying entity.lookAt(camera.position) I am missing an angle rotation based on the current angle (last function call of the example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to model a fan is like so:

```
var fan = new THREE.Mesh( ... );

var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( pivot );
pivot.lookAt( camera.position );

pivot.add( fan );
```

Then in the animation loop (assuming the fan mesh by default faces the positive-z axis),

```
fan.rotation.z += 0.01;
```

three.js r.68

Comment: Unfortunately I could not see any difference compared to just leaving away the whole pivot part, but your answer pointed me to the solition, which is...

Initialization:
`var angle = 0;
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);`

Loop:
`angle += 0.01 * deltaTime;
mesh.lookAt(camera.position);
mesh.rotateOnAxis(axis, angle);`

Now the "fan" always faces the camera while rotating. Thus rotateOnAxis(...) seems to be just the functionality of ang_rotate(...) in my example.

Comment: 1. My solution is much less computationally intensive, as you only need to call `lookAt()` once. 2. You did not find THE solution, you found a different solution. 3. You could have used `rotateZ( angle )`.

Comment: That is definitely true. I don't know why it did not work as I implemented it, but in the end, for my speciffic case I need to do the orientation and rotation only once as it is some kind of energy discharge that only lasts for a very short time. I'm glad I finally got a solution, as I struggled with it for at least 5 hours yesterday...